# What is the starting point for running unit-tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

Let's say I'd like to create my own unit-test framework for .NET. How would I do that?

I mean where do I start in a sense of which APIs or interfaces I need to hook up to or how would I tell Visual Studio *hey, this is my unit-test framework, please use this for running tests*?

Are there any books on that topic or any official APIs in Visual Studio that I can use?

I'm not looking for any code. I can write code. I just need to know how I make this code run as a unit-test runner?

To anticipate your questions: it's not debatable why I want to do this. Maybe I have some ideas that other frameworks don't offer or maybe I think I can do it better. Whatever it is, I'd really like to know where is the starting point for running unit-tests with a unit-test framework... if there is any?

...or maybe there no standard at all and every unit-test framework uses its own *hacks*? OK, this would probably be terrible... but if this is how the world works, so be it.

Comment: you mean something like this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2012/07/31/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter/

Comment: I would suggest probably checking out the public repos of the available runners and see if there are any commonalities.

Comment: Look at some existing frameworks such as Fixie https://github.com/fixie/fixie or xUnit https://xunit.github.io/  (They are similar but fixie is smaller and probably easier to decipher)

Comment: @gofal3 I guess this is it! Searching for the interfaces lead me to the [vstest](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest) repository that looks like the core for creating unit-test frameworks. Thanks! It was the _magic_ word _adapter_ that I couldn't come up with ;-)

Comment: @Nkosi yeah, reverse-engineering is always an option but it costs a lot of time. It's actually much easier when you know what you are looking for. Now, knowing the interfaces it'll be much easier to analyze them.

Comment: @AndersForsgren thanks for the _fixie_ link, I didn't know this one. I'll take a look at it. Now I know what I should be paying more attention to.